# How to solve a system of N quadratic equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Could you recommend me some book or website where I could learn about systems of nonlinear equations?

I have found several sources, but everywhere only a set of two equations is considered.

Comment: Are they perchance hyperspheres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a book on [Solving Systems of Polynomial Equations](https://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/cbms.pdf) by Bernd Sturmfels. Certainly there are enough sources where systems of polynomial equations are considered, with more than just two equations.